# Log loss and metrics on INFO level

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, allennlp

I use AWS SageMaker to run a training with AllenNLP. In order to track the loss and metrics I need to have them printed on the log INFO level during training (or at least after each epoch). However, when I run the training all loss and metric information is printed to the console without using the logger:

```
2021-07-12 16:39:25,799 - INFO - allennlp.training.trainer - Epoch 2/24
2021-07-12 16:39:25,803 - INFO - allennlp.training.trainer - Worker 0 memory usage: 1.5G
2021-07-12 16:39:25,806 - INFO - allennlp.training.trainer - Training
accuracy: 0.1116, batch_loss: 0.4598, loss: 0.4742 ||: 100%|##########| 8/8 [00:13<00:00,  1.64s/it]
2021-07-12 16:39:40,229 - INFO - allennlp.training.trainer - Validating
accuracy: 0.2000, batch_loss: 0.4377, loss: 0.4215 ||: 100%|##########| 2/2 [00:03<00:00,  1.87s/it]
```

So far, I could not find anything in the issues or on StackOverflow. As I said, having the loss and metrics logged on INFO level once per epoch would be totally fine.

Also [in this example](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-guide/issues/135) it seems like the loss and metrics are logged the way I would like to have it.

Comment: If you use `ConsoleLoggerCallback` in your trainer (this can be done by either explicitly specifying the callback in your config, or setting `enable_default_callbacks` to `True`), that should log the metrics at INFO level once per epoch.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: Actually, it was a version issue. I was using `2.1.0` for some docker reason. With the update on `2.6.0` it prints as expected by default. Thank you!